# SQL SET Statement C# Parameters

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I'm working in C# with SQL, and am having issues figuring out how to pass a C# variable into an SQL SET statement.  I understand how to pass a parameter to the "WHERE" section of an SQL SELECT statement, but I can't find any information on how to add parameters to a "SET" section of an UPDATE statement.  This is the code that I'm turning into a Stored Procedure:

```
string sql = " update pay_control set payroll_type_cd = :payroll_type_cd, paystart_dt = :paystart_dt, payend_dt = :payend_dt, check_dt = :check_dt, ";
            sql += "eff_dt = :eff_dt, init_dt = :init_dt, close_dt = :close_dt, active = :active, completed = :completed,  release_pay = :release_pay where pay_control_id = :pay_control_id";

            List<UserInput> listUserInput = new List<UserInput>();

            listUserInput.Add(new UserInput(":payroll_type_cd", "System.Int64", userInputs.PayrollTypeCd.ToString()));
            listUserInput.Add(new UserInput(":pay_control_id", "System.Int64", userInputs.PayControlId.ToString()));
            listUserInput.Add(new UserInput(":paystart_dt", "System.DateTime", userInputs.PaystartDt.ToShortDateString()));
            listUserInput.Add(new UserInput(":payend_dt", "System.DateTime", userInputs.PayendDt.ToShortDateString()));
            listUserInput.Add(new UserInput(":check_dt", "System.DateTime", userInputs.CheckDt.ToShortDateString()));
            listUserInput.Add(new UserInput(":eff_dt", "System.DateTime", userInputs.EffDt.ToShortDateString()));
            listUserInput.Add(new UserInput(":init_dt", "System.DateTime", userInputs.InitDt.ToShortDateString()));
            listUserInput.Add(new UserInput(":close_dt", "System.DateTime", userInputs.CloseDt.ToShortDateString()));
            listUserInput.Add(new UserInput(":active", "System.String", userInputs.Active));
            listUserInput.Add(new UserInput(":completed", "System.String", userInputs.Completed));
            listUserInput.Add(new UserInput(":release_pay", "System.String", userInputs.ReleasePay));
```

I'm not planning on making the "listUserInput" lines part of the Stored Procedure, but I can't figure out how to pass the information from the "listUserInput" to the Stored Procedure.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: How is defined the UserInput type? How do you use that listUserInput?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a [MySqlCommand](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html) and paramerterized statements, for example:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand cmd;
cmd = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand();

cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE pay_control SET payroll_type_cd = @payroll_type_cd)";
cmd.Prepare();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payroll_type_cd", 1);
```

Comment: Okay, so it's pretty much the same as I would do it in a where statement!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reason to keep that UserInput class, I would use directly a `List<MySqlParameter>` instead.

```
List<MySqlParameter> listParams = new List<MySqlParameter>()
{
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = ":payroll_type_cd", 
                        MySqlDbType=MySqlDbType.Int64, 
                        Value= Convert.ToInt64(userInputs.PayrollTypeCd)},
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = ":pay_control_id", 
                        MySqlDbType=MySqlDbType.Int64, 
                        Value = Convert.ToInt64(userInputs.PayControlId)},
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = ":paystart_dt", 
                        MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Date,
                        Value = userInputs.PaystartDt},
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = ":payend_dt", 
                        MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Date,
                        Value = userInputs.PayendDt},
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = ":check_dt", 
                        MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Date,
                        Value = userInputs.CheckDt},
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = ":eff_dt", 
                        MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Date,
                        Value = userInputs.EffDt},
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = ":init_dt", 
                        MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Date,
                        Value = userInputs.InitDt},
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = ":close_dt", 
                        MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Date,
                        Value = userInputs.CloseDt},
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = ":active", 
                        MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar,
                        Size = ???? datatable field size here ????
                        Value = userInputs.Active},
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = ":completed", 
                        MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar,
                        Size = ???? datatable field size here ????
                        Value = userInputs.Completed},
   new MySqlParameter { ParameterName = ":release_pay", 
                        MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar,
                        Size = ???? datatable field size here ????
                        Value = userInputs.ReleasePay}
```

};

And now you could create the MySqlCommand to receive this list of parameters

```
   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("userProcName", connection);
   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.AddRange(listParams.ToArray());
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Notice that with parameters you shoud set carefully the datatype that is passed to the stored procedure. So creating the MySqlParameter one by one allows to define precisely the datatype of the parameter.